# Double vision with the Cardboard - Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I am trying to create a small android game in unity for the google cardboard, but the problem is that my 5.7 inch phone is too big. The standard profile in the SDK doesn’t work with my phone and I see double images.

As far as I know, I need to change the profile using a QR-code or set a default URI in some script. I have created a QR with the 
[Viewer Profile Generator](https://www.google.com/get/cardboard/viewerprofilegenerator/)
and it works great with the standard Cardboard app, but I do not understand how to use it with my program. Syncing the game with the Cardboard app only seems to work with iOS, and changing the *DefaultDeviceProfile* in the *Cardboard.cs* doesn’t do anything for me.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your phone model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your phone is running Marshmallow, which has the new runtime permissions model.  Cardboard SDK is not fully up to speed with this model, because it does not prompt the user to add the needed permissions, it just silently fails.  In this case, the needed permission is READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, which grants access to the sdcard, where the QR code data is stored.  For now, the best way around this is to make sure that targetSDK = 22 in your project's AndroidManifest (in Assets/Plugins/Android).  For a specific app that is already built, you can activate the "storage" permission in the app's App Info screen.

Comment: Thank you! The Manifest had alredy the targetSDK set at 22, the problem was that I had moved the _Plugins_ file

Comment: Please add to your answer that changing DefaultDeviceProfile  will not working if Cardboard application from google is not installed on mobile device.